# Menu item events

Tags: blackberry-simulator

I want to create a menu in my application with one menuitem. When the user clicks in the menuitem, a Screen must be loaded.  I am new in Blackberry so please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want a web page to open in the browser? Take a look at `BrowserSession.displayPage()`. You can obtain a BrowserSession with `Browser.getDefaultSession()`.

Comment: Inside the run() method of the MenuItem, just do `getUiApplication().pushScreen(screen_to_load);`, possibly after building the screen.